# How to add roughness to a surface using modifiers?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mesh

I'm trying to make a roughened parchment-like material. I don't want to just use a texture, because I want to take a low-angle shot that lets me see the actual bumps in the surface.

I currently have the parchment represented using a single plane mesh. Is there a modifier I can use to deform the mesh in order to add roughness to it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, though you'll probably want to use two for maximum effect; I recommend applying a *Subdivision surface modifier* ('Simple', not 'Catmull-Clark'), and then applying a *Displace modifier*. If your geometry is sufficiently complex it should work fine.

The *Subdivision Surface modifier* adds vertices to your mesh, then the *Displace modifier* uses those vertices to add the roughness you're looking for.

*Before Modifiers*
[image]

*After Modifiers*
[image]

You can, of course, use different settings for the Displace texture if you want to achieve different kinds of roughness.

Comment: One thing I would suggest, is to use an image of parchment for the displacement texture, as it will come out more realistic.

Answer (score 5):

> I don't want to just use a texture, because I want to take a low-angle shot that lets me see the actual bumps in the surface

Since recently, you **can use a texture** and have **actual bumps**. This works in combination with Cycles only, and makes use of the *Material*'s *Displacement* property.

First, you should use the *Experimental Feature Set* in the *Render* panel:

[image]

Add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and enable *Adaptive*:

[image]

The trick here is that, by using *Adaptive*, the size of subdivisions will be dependent on how much the surface is close to the point of view. So you'll have each screen-space pixel displace independently from the neighboring ones, but without the need to subdivide the whole mesh by the same amount.

In the *Node/Shader Editor*, plug the desired texture into *Displacement*. If Blender>2.80, you should use a *Displacement* node, otherwise (2.79) just plug the height in the *Material Output*.

[image]

(If Blender 2.79, under *Material > Settings* set *Displacement* to "Both")

[image]

The bumps are now real, i.e. affecting the geometry, but non destructive, i.e. not affecting *Edit mode* vertices. In the gif, the geometry is just a 4-vertex plane:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Once your surface is subdivided with sufficiently small faces, you can use *Mesh Tools -> Deform: Randomize* to add roughness. Fine-tune using the tool parameters shown below.
[image: Randomize]

My result:

[image: Result]

If you prefer to have bumps instead of spikes, you can again *Mesh Tools -> Add: Subdivide* (with four or five cuts) and select *Smoothness* = 1.

[image: Bumps instead of spikes]
[image: Resulting bumps]