# Paper model effect from Royal Institution titles

Tags: modeling, materials

There's a [clip in the Blender 2013 demo reel](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=1XZGulDxz9o&t=32) that consists of a fly-through of a paper cut-out model. (32 seconds in)

I'd like to have a go at recreating that look. Does anybody have any tips? What are the characteristics that make it instantly recognizable as paper? Is it a subtle texture on the paper itself? Is it the hand-drawn outlines on the edges? Or is it something else, such as the indoor lighting or the focal length?

Comment: I would say it is a combination of all those things. Are you looking for tips on how to create those effects?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/362/how-to-add-roughness-to-a-surface-using-modifiers

Comment: @gandalf3 I'm an ambitious (almost) beginner, so I'll absorb any tips you have on any of that.

Comment: @Derecho For tips on how to create those individual effects, you will probably be best off asking about each one in an individual question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My thoughts:

- Every surface must contain a paper texture, even of only slightly visible.
- Make the paper look a little used (dirt, coffee stains, bit crumbled up, [more hints](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?129727-does-blender-has-a-dirt-texture-plugin))
- Light the place as if it was miniature (soft shadows, big lights)
- Focus as if it was macro (blurry background)
- When drawing on the paper, use near-real pencil.
- Cycles - definitely use cycles for this.
- Freestyle is not a must, but can help.
- Extra help is small dust particles on the ground and flying around.

I think the strong point of that video is realistic lighting: very varied sources and realistic bouncing, warm temperature. Also it doesn't stay on too long, I bet you can get a better result if you try!

Comment: maybe some translucency for the material as well?

Comment: @krivar Thanks -- that sounds like really useful stuff.

Comment: I agree with all that, maybe add a bunch of "look-at" constraints for the character and the things on the desk.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the look is mostly influenced by the outlines, you could achieve something similar by using freestyle.

You can enable freestyle in the render tab:

[image]

In the render layer tab you find several options to control freestyle

[image]

A nice [blog post on freestyle](http://freestyleintegration.wordpress.com/)