# How do i convert a blender texture into a 3D printable format?

Tags: texturing, modifiers, geometry

How do I convert the Blender texturing  techniques discussed in the link below into geometry so that I can print them on a 3D printer, and are there any limitations that I should be aware of?

[How to add roughness to a surface using modifiers?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/362/how-to-add-roughness-to-a-surface-using-modifiers/226982?noredirect=1#comment382752_226982)

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the texture to a "displace" modifier, you can apply this modifier and have it affect your geometry permanently and 3D-printable. (The "displacement" from the material editor will not work for this, the texture needs to be used by the "displace" modifier.)

[image]

There are only two things you should be aware of:

- if you have any other modifiers (such as subdivision), you need to apply them before you apply the displace
- obviously, the effect of your displace-modifier should be strong enough to be actually resolvable by your 3D printer