# Is there a Musgrave Texture color output in Blender 2.9?

Tags: node-editor, displacement

So I needed a plane to have bumps and while researching, I came across [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/362/how-to-add-roughness-to-a-surface-using-modifiers?newreg=3ee783931bf2495d815443c968fb66ed), which answered my question pretty much. As I followed along with the second answer by Nicola Sap, I saw that his Musgrave Texture node had a color output and mine did not. He was, AFAIK, using Blender 2.80 and I am currently using Blender 2.92. Is there a way to have a color output on a Musgrave Texture node or do I need to use something else to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

From the [manual of version 2.80](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/render/shader_nodes/textures/musgrave.html):

> **Outputs**
> **Color**
> Texture color output. It is grayscale, all three RGB components are equal to the value of the Factor output.
> **Factor**
> Texture intensity output.

So you can just use the factor output as you would have used the color output, it makes no difference.

Comment: Be careful !! The factor output can be negative (which may be a problem if used in a bump map, and will cause artifacts if plugged into a Roughness input), while the color output is always a positive array of 3 or 4 values. The solution is to use a map range node or a clamp node afterwards to restrain it to positive values

Comment: I only have a Height output, is that OK too?